# Laravel 5.2 After moving content from "public" to root i got many wrong paths with bower_components

Tags: php, laravel-5, bower

I've completed my Laravel project and now I want to get out `/public` from my URL address.

I did it like this:

1. Put all contents of root (except public folder) to the new folder called `local`.
2. I've moved all the contents of `public` to `root` and deleted `public` folder.
3. I've edited `index.php` file and updated paths to:

   - `require __DIR__.'/local/bootstrap/autoload.php'`;
   - `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/local/bootstrap/app.php'`;

Now the problem is that I get `bower_components` errors and I don't know where or how update this:

[Here are console errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwyKH.png)

Since I do not have public folder it should look like this:

```
vvfoodD/admin/bower_components/...
```

---

I've also added folder structure of my project, maybe it will help. It is like in my Laravel project root I have another project called `admin`.

[Here is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwyKH.png)

**So my question is where and how can I update this?**

Comment: If you set up Laravel properly you shouldn't get "public" in your URL address to begin with.

Comment: Sounds like your server configuration is not properly set as your document root should be the public folder and this should not show in URLs

Comment: Sry guys, I just added my folder structure of project. You can check it and maybe you get more clear about my problem.

Comment: Just set up a virtual host and set the server root directory to be the laravel directory, that way public will not be in the path at all. I'm sure there's lots of tutorials on how to do that (quick google search revealed [something at laravel recipies](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you have wrong paths set up in your view. Can you try removing /public from the paths to bower in your view?

Comment: Paths are set correctly. Everything messed up then I moved all things to "local" folder and "public" content to folders "admin" root. I edited recently diagram of folder structure you can check :)

Comment: can you put a snippet of your html code 2-3 script tags  in explanation? and where are your views located?

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you! Haven't expected that someone could leave in resources paths in laravel like this:
<link href="../public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Few guys worked before me and left this present for me... Problem was with wrong resources paths in view file. I know how properly fix this. Thank you. Just haven't expected that...

Comment: I know the feeling I've had that problem few times. :) Happy future coding. ;)